# python image unified transform

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library, gimp

I looking for a way to transform a Image into a another one.
The tool from GIMP work perfectly for my task: "Unified Transform Tool"
But is there a way to do it with a python lib? Like openCV or PIL?

My Goal is it to add images to mockup photos and I have to do it automaticly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the GIMP technique, but it looks like a *"Scale Rotate Translate"* kind of thing which you can do in Python with [wand](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.10/guide/distortion.html?highlight=Scale%20rotate%20translate#scale-rotate-translate).

You can do the same thing in the Terminal with [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#distort). Tutorial and examples [here](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#methods).

Comment: not exactly "Scale Rotate Translate" but "distort perspective" did the job! thx.